# What can I do with Villagers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So there's these villagers (called `TESTIFICATE`?!) inhabiting my villages. Can I interact with them? What happens if I kill them?

Comment: What does "Post is related to a rapidly changing event" mean?

Comment: @fireDude67 I would assume it's because the version of Minecraft that the OP is talking about is 1.9 PreRelease. It's basically a beta of a beta, if that makes sense. Even though the villagers don't have a purpose yet, they most likely will in the near future.

Comment: Where is the Murder tag when you need it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Villagers were introduced in the beta 1.9 pre-release, and, for the most part, act like passive mobs: they'll get up in your grill and walk around without a care in the world.  When you kill them, they don't drop anything.

In addition, 1.2 brought [a number of changes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.2) to mob AI such as villagers:

- entering houses at night and leave them in the morning
- breeding to populate all the houses in a village
- enabling the automatic creation of [iron golems](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem) that protect them

The first new behavior—entering houses at night and leaving them in the morning—allows you to use villagers as [a poor man's daylight detector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTphS.jpg).

Finally, as of [snapshot 12w21a](http://www.mojang.com/2012/05/minecraft-snapshot-week-21/), villagers power Minecraft's economy by trading items with players.

Comment: The villagers themselves don't really do anything to defend themselves, do they?  The iron golems do the work.

Comment: @JohntheGreen You are correct: villagers don't defend themselves. Updated answer based on what was finally released (realized my previous comment was a bit unclear as to what I was denying).

Answer (score -1):

They also pick up food, but different ones like or dislike different kinds of food.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score -2):

I have Played Minecraft for a few now, but ever since i started, i spawned a Villager Egg. To me it seems they:

At night, they go in any possible Home Nearby,
They are capable of climbing ladders, and walking up stairs
They run away from zombies,enderman, and spiders
Soon, when a new version comes out, they will be able to breed and have kids, that YOU can name.
They mainly eat Cake,but some are different.

Comment: They run away from only zombies, and do not eat cake. Get your facts right.